# Is it normal to make subclasses of NSManagedObjects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

As the title states: is it normal to make subclasses of `NSManagedObjects`? When you have e.g. `Item`, would you use the `NSManagedObject` with key/value or have a `Item` class?

And if you use a subclass how would you send the an `Item` instance to a common Core Data "DAO" class? You can't use the initializer method `init`, and since you don't have the context outside the DAO how would you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite common to subclass NSManagedObject. Then you set that class to be the Class of your Entity in the Model Editor. You can then define properties any use those instead of KVC. See [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started), especially the Autogenerating Model Files part.

Comment: Okey, but what about instantiating those objects? I have the context in the repository, and I want to pass the object as an argument to one of the repository methods. I can't use the `init` method.

Comment: I'm not sure what repository you mean. You initalize new objects like this: `MyObject *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject" 
inManagedObjectContext:context];`

Comment: Nope. Not what I am looking for.

Comment: If you want to do something at initialization of an NSManagedObject, you should override awakeFromInsert instead of init.